# Firefox redirection to dnssearch.com

Tags: macos, firefox, browser, isp

***My Environment***
OSX El Capitain
FireFox 44.0.2
Service Provider : Time Warner Cable
Issue only happens in Firefox, Safari and Chrome are okay

**Issue Summary**
Whenever i type incorrect web address like for example bankofamerica it redirects me to http://www.dnsrsearch.com/index.php?origURL=http%3A//bankofamerica/&r=&bc=
[image]

This page on dnsrsearch gave me preference option where i even disabled it
[image]

***What i have tried inside about:config***  
keyword.enabled;false  
browser.fixup.alternate.enabled;false  
  
I also found several entries like following where bankofamerica is replaced by the website i typed in past  
  
browser.fixup.domainwhitelist.bankofamerica;false

Regards

Comment: Browser typically cache 301 redirects pretty intensively.  Making sure the setting is off in TWC settings first, clear your cache, then reboot the PC and your router (many today's routers maintain there own DNS cache).

Comment: Rebooting all those units didn't help still redirecting to http://www.dnsrsearch.com/index.php?origURL=http%3A//bankofamerica/&r=&bc=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Backup your bookmarks](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/export-firefox-bookmarks-to-backup-or-transfer), delete your ~/Library/Application Support/Firefox and  ~/Library/Application Support/Mozilla folders from your home folder. Remove and re-install Firefox.
2. You can use an alternate DNS provider. [Google’s Public DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/?csw=1) is a popular option. [OpenDNS](https://www.opendns.com/) is another option. By default OpenDNS does a similar redirect but have an opt-out option.

Comment: Followed 1 but after that when i type bankofamerica i get "yes take me to bankofamerica' or no thanks if i click bankofamerica it still takes me to timewarner redirection so it seems it's not fully disabled yet. i could just leave it alone but it would be nice to disable this TWC redirection

Comment: can you please elaborate more on your point 2

Comment: Go to System Preferences->Network->Advanced->DNS. Delete anything that is there and try replacing it with 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 and see if you still have the problem.